# How to prove a group is cyclic

Tags: group-theory, soft-question

What are some methods for proving that a group is cyclic?

For example, I found this link https://www.math3ma.com/blog/ways-to-show-a-group-is-abelian for different ways to prove a group is abelian. Could anyone make a list like this for different ways to show a group is cyclic?

Comment: Honestly, that list is at least in some parts very silly. "I don't want to prove that $ab=ba$ for all $a$ and $b$, so instead prove that $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ is trivial for all $a$ and $b$!" That's **the same thing** and takes **the same amount of work**. Likewise, showing $|Z(G)|=|G|$ (which only works for finite groups) means verifying that $Z(G)=G$, means verifying that every element commutes with every element...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a (short) list for recognizing a cyclic group:

1. If your group is finite of order $n$, try to give a group isomorphism to $C_n$.
2. If your group is infinite, try to give a group isomorphism to $\Bbb Z=C_{\infty}$.
3. In general, try to find a generator $g$. If you succedd then $G$ is cyclic and consists of the integral powers of $g$.

For example, take $G$ as the subgroup of $GL_2(\Bbb Z)$ consisting of the matrices
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & k \cr 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
for all $k\in \Bbb Z$. Can you decide whether or not $G$ is cyclic using 1.,2. or 3.?

Comment: If the group is finite and abelian, it is the direct product of cyclic groups. You need to check that all of the cyclic groups have coprime order with each other. If it is infinite, it reduces to finding a homomorphism with $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @DonThousand I think the question only asks for cyclic groups. A priori we do not know whether our given group is abelian or finite.

Comment: I'd add as "0." bullet point: if your group is finite of order $p$, $p$ prime, then it is cyclic (and every non-unit element is a generator).

Comment: @Luka yes, or even better, if $\gcd(n,\phi(n))=1$, then $G$ is cyclic - see OEIS.